# cin object - c++

Tags: c++, cin

```
   #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    struct list
    {
        int data;
        list *next;
    };

    list *node, *tail = NULL, *head = NULL;
    void add2list();
    void extrem();

    int main()
    {
        add2list();
        extrem();

        return 0;
    }

    void add2list()
    {
        int input;
        cout << "Adding values to list :\n";
        cout << ">>";

        while(cin >> input)
        {
            node = new list;
            node->data = input;
            node->next = NULL;

            if (head == NULL)
            {
                head = node;
                tail = node;
            }
            else
             {
                tail->next = node;
                tail = node;
             }
        cout << ">>";
        }
    }

    void extrem()
    {
       int x, y;
       cin >> x >> y;
    }
```

when i run this program it's only execute the add2list function ????

I've added cin.clear(), but the problem is not solved, why??

somecan give clear explaintion about how can I solve this

and When is the use of cin.clear() object useful؟؟

sorry 4 my bad english

Comment: How do you know extreme isn't being executed? It doesn't do anything anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons why `std::cin >> value` can fail:

1. `std::cin` has reached its end (e.g. by using Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z, depending on which system you are using)
2. The pending character cannot be parsed as a `value`, i.e., in your case as `int`. The offending character is, however, not extracted.

Obviously, there isn't anything you can in the first situation: once you have reached the end of the standard input stream there is no way to extend it. So, let's assume you entered an invalid character, e.g., a letter. Trying to read this letter as an `int` will fail and cause `std::ios_base::failbit` to be set. Before you can do anything to the stream you need to `clear()` it. Once you have cleared `std::ios_base::failbit` you can `ignore()` the next character and then try again. That is, if you add after your call do `add2list()` the following two calls things should be fine, assuming there is only one offending letter (otherwise you might need to ignore more characters):

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is broken: Both `cin >> input` and `cin >> x >> y` attempt to extract `int`s from the stream. When the `while` loop in  `add2list` breaks, it is no longer possible to extract `int`s from the stream. Resetting the error flags doesn't suddenly make parsable data appear in the stream. When you attempt to read into `x`, you'll just fail again for the same reason that you broke from the loop.

You need to find a better way to read distinct parts of the input, i.e. one for building the list, and another for reading further data. A general *line*-based approach (via `std::getline`) might be a good start, and you could implement a simple shell that takes commands like "create list" etc.